# Error 500 deployement Django on IIS Server

Tags: python, django, iis, cgi

I try to deploy a django app to a IIS Server. During this step, I find this error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> scriptProcessor could not be found in  application
>   configuration

My directory folder are: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp (where i Found manage.py)

in wwwroot\MyApp\web.config I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have into my IIS Manager, into my handlermapping of my Sites\MyApp this datas:
Request path: *

> Module: FastCgiModule Executable (optional):
>   C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe|C:\Users\ybe\Envs\IntranetBenu\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

If I try to go to C:\Users\ybe\Envs\MyApp\Scripts|Lib I find the files need.

Directory browsing are checked for Time, Size Extension and Date (but not long date)

The MyApp ApplicationPool are Started.

Have you any idea of this error ?

Thanks per advance,

Comment: Very likely the space in the path is the cause. Install Python to `C:\Python37` and try that.

Comment: same errors with C:\Python37\python.exe|C:\Envs\MyApp\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

Answer (score 0):

The problem persist. I changed the installation Python to c:\Python37 and moved the Env to C:\Envs